# Difference between Canon 18-55mm IS II and IS STM?

Tags: lens, canon, comparison, canon-700d

I am a newbie into the photography world and would like to buy a DSLR. I am currently shooting with my phone and usually take photos with auto mode. While choosing for a camera I have narrowed my search Canon 700D. However, i am still trying to decide onto the lens to buy.

In India, there are 2 options available. 18-55 + 55-250 IS II and 18-55 IS STM lens. Both cost almost the same.

Can anyone guide me as to which option I should go for? Can 18-55 STM suffice my needs of general photography? If so, I can go for STM, or else I would rather like to go with IS II since I get 2 lenses. May be once I grow from novice to expert, I can surely look for other options as well like 18-135 or so.

Comment: Maybe do some more searching. You might be able to find a 700D or 650D with an 18-135mm IS STM. Which I would take over either of those packages. The difference between the 700D and the 650D are quite trivial.

Answer (score 0):

STM is really only useful for video. If you have no interest in video then there's not much value in the STM feature itself.

However, you may want to look into the quality of the STM lens vs the the non STM lens. STM itself doesn't contribute to image quality, but is part of the naming convention and these are two different lenses with different optical quality.

Now, in my opinion, if you'll use the 55-250 (depends on what you're shooting), get the bundle.

Comment: The STM version is also much better for still photography.  Here are the reasons why:  1) The STM versions are sharper than the Micro Motor versions 2) STM AF is faster and quieter. 3) The front element does not rotate on the 18-55mm STM  4) The STM version has a proper manual focus ring. 5) The STM version has "Full Time Manual Focus" available 6) The lens hood  for the STM version is a proper "petal" hood. http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y17/msowsun/photo%20stuff/Photo14/5D3_0898a.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Jumping from phone photo to DSLR is a little much.  I would recommend instead going to a high end point and shoot and shoot in manual mode to learn what all those things do, then switch to DSLR and lens combo with capabilities specific to what you found lacking in your point and shoot.

Photography have specific gear needed for different photos.  Do you want high speed action shots?  Scenic views?  Close up subjects?  Night sky?  All those special 'scene' modes usually needs a particular lens to do well.  Generic wide range zooms do work, but you won't know what's wrong with the photo until you have more experience.